# How to have the fadeout effect while removing element from ng-repeat without using ngAnimate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css

Can we have animation using CSS-3 or Javascript without using ngAnimate on ng-repeat?  I want to avaoid using ng-Animate because of performance and the animation is not smooth.

Please suggest me the alternative way or any link where i can find the solution.

Thanks

Comment: [ng-Animate uses CSS for its transitions.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations) So there really isn't a difference between using one over the other.

Comment: you can use `ngClass` and add your custom class based on a condition, but as @MatthewGreen said, `ngAnimate` is *very* smooth as it can use css animation/transition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never use ngAnimate, but animate.css. 
Here comes the code, http://plnkr.co/edit/DjuxVfOjcUa0N4nOCSGN?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-rc.2" data-semver="1.3.0-rc.2" src="  https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://rawgit.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.css" />
  </head>

  <body ng-app>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="no in [1,2,3,4,5]" ng-click="myvar=!myvar" 
        ng-class="{animated:true, fadeOut:myvar, fadeIn: !myvar}">
        {{no}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```